# Debounce method call from BindableObject in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I am new to Swift and even more so to SwiftUI. I started to create a little basic project. I use Github API to fetch repositories list.

So I created a "Search Bar" like since SwiftUI doesn't have a SearchBar component. I would like to perform the fetch operation everytime my Textfield content is changed.

I don't want the fetch method to be called too often. I decided to debounce it. I'm facing a problem, I don't find/understand example.

I tried to implement a debounce solution but it doesn't work, my application just crash.

Here's my BindableObject

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ReposStore: BindableObject {

    private var service: GithubService

    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    @Published var searchText: String = ""

    var repos: [Repository] = [] {
        didSet {
            didChange.send()
        }
    }

    var error: String = "" {
        didSet {
            didChange.send()
        }
    }

    var test: String = "" {
        didSet {
            didChange.send()
        }
    }

    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil

    init(service: GithubService) {
        self.service = service


        cancellable = AnyCancellable($searchText
            .removeDuplicates()
            .debounce(for: 2, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .flatMap { self.fetch(matching: $0) }
            .assign(to: \.test, on: self)
        )
    }

    func fetch(matching query: String = "") {
        print("### QUERY \(query)")
        self.service.getUserRepositories(matching: query) { [weak self] result in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("### RESULT HERE \(result)")
                switch result {
                case .success(let repos): self?.repos = repos
                case .failure(let error): self?.error = error.localizedDescription
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my View

```
import SwiftUI

struct RepositoryList : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var repoStore: ReposStore
    @State private var userName: String = ""

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {

                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass").background(Color.blue).padding(.leading, 10.0)
                        TextField($repoStore.repoUser, placeholder: Text("Search")).background(Color.red)
                            .padding(.vertical, 4.0)
                            .padding(.trailing, 10.0)
                    }
                    .border(Color.secondary, width: 1, cornerRadius: 5)
                        .padding()

                    List {
                        ForEach(self.repoStore.repos) { repository in
                            NavigationLink(
                                destination: RepositoryDetail(repository: repository).environmentObject(self.repoStore)
                            ) {
                                RepositoryRow(repository: repository)
                            }
                        }

                    }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Repositories"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to use a Timer and schedule and action every 8 seconds but this method cause my application to crash.

More, I don't really know if it's a good practice to declare a function with "@objc" annotation ...

Could someone help me to implement a correct way to debounce a method inside a BindableObject ?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Combine already has a debounce operator.

Comment: Thank you, could you be more precise ?

Comment: I'd say watch the WWDC 2019 videos about the Combine framework. They use exactly the same example you're dealing with: a network operation that we don't want to perform too often as the user types in a text field.

Comment: Thank you I will watch it :)

Comment: So I've edited my question with my new code. I've been watching WWDC 2019 but I'm still not capable to call my async method inside "flatMap" instruction. Could you give me some clue / tell me if my code is better ?

Comment: I'm looking for the same solution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally managed to set up the debounce.

If it could helps someone, here's my implementation :

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class Store : ObservableObject {
  private var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
  @Published var searchText: String= ""
  @Published var user: User? = nil

  init() {
    cancellable = AnyCancellable(
      $searchText.removeDuplicates()
        .debounce(for: 0.8, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink { searchText in 
          self.searchUser()
      })
  }

  func searchUser() {
    var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://api.github.com/users/\(searchText)")!

    urlComponents.queryItems = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "access_token", value: EnvironmentConfiguration.shared.github_token)
     ]

    var request = URLRequest(url: urlComponents.url!)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    searchCancellable = URLSession.shared.send(request: request)
        .decode(type: User.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .map { $0 }
        .replaceError(with: nil)
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .assign(to: \.user, on: self)
  }
}

extension URLSession {
  func send(request: URLRequest) -> AnyPublisher<Data, URLSessionError> {
        dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            .mapError { URLSessionError.urlError($0) }
            .flatMap { data, response -> AnyPublisher<Data, URLSessionError> in
                guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                    return .fail(.invalidResponse)
                }

                guard 200..<300 ~= response.statusCode else {
                    return .fail(.serverErrorMessage(statusCode: response.statusCode,
                                                     data: data))
                }

                return .just(data)
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

  enum URLSessionError: Error {
      case invalidResponse
      case serverErrorMessage(statusCode: Int, data: Data)
      case urlError(URLError)
  }
}

extension Publisher {

    static func empty() -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> {
        return Empty()
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    static func just(_ output: Output) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> {
        return Just(output)
            .catch { _ in AnyPublisher<Output, Failure>.empty() }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    static func fail(_ error: Failure) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> {
        return Fail(error: error)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

struct User: Hashable, Identifiable, Decodable {
    var id: Int
    var login: String
    var avatar_url: URL
    var name: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, login, avatar_url, name
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that introduce a retain cycle (`cancellable` and `self`)?

Comment: can you please give me full demo of this code or any github link?